# Класс для инкапсуляции главных объектов

Tags: c++, ооп

Уважаемое сообщество, у меня возникла следующая дилемма – у меня есть **главный класс**, который **владеет** рядом объектов: *указателем на окошко, стэком указателей на состояния, контейнерами поддерживаемых шрифтов, настроек и прочего-прочего*. В общем, множество различных штук.

Классы-состояния должны иметь ссылки на эти объекты из главного класса (получают их в конструкторе), чтобы тем или иным образом **пользоваться** ими. Но, так как этих объектов достаточно много и, при масштабировании программы, их кол-во может увеличиваться – конструкторы состояний раздуваются до внушительных масштабов. Было принято решение **инкапсулировать** все эти объекты в одном отдельном классе `GeneralValues` и назначить владение его экземпляром в главный класс.

Таким образом, в конструктор состояний можно просто передавать ссылку на объект класса `GeneralValues`, и через неё получать доступ ко всем объектам, что находятся в нём. И памяти это будет требовать меньше: вместо множества отдельных ссылок на объекты, которые находятся в пользовании, можно будет просто сделать одну ссылку на объект, в котором все эти остальные объекты собраны.

*Вопрос:*
**Правильное ли это будет решение? Есть ли в такой архитектуре какие-нибудь подводные камни?**

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82

Comment: @user7860670, 
1. Этот класс не содержит вообще никакой функциональности. Он просто собирает в себе ряд объектов, чтобы их не приходилось запихивать каждый по отдельности по 10+ штук в конструктор класса-состояния.
2. Объект этого класса не является глобальным.
3. Он не делает ничего, кроме своей главной задачи - просто сгруппировать данные в единый компонент. Как struct в чистом Си. Поэтому, не думаю, что это даже близко "Божественный объект"

Comment: "объект, который хранит в себе «слишком много»"